# Conditionally setting variable with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query. I am trying to only add the values, if the value is not null so the whole variable doesnt end up as a null. Obviously this query below is erroring out, but I do not want to use an ISNULL check on the test column because it puts a comma at the end of the variable text. How would I do this without having the comma at the end of the variable text. Sometimes there will be nulls in the test column, and sometimes there will not be.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    test varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT 'adfasdfasd'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL


DECLARE @DocID varchar(max)

SELECT CASE WHEN test IS NOT NULL THEN @DocID = COALESCE(@DocID + ',' ,'')  + test END
FROM @Test

SELECT @DocID
```

Comment: Why not just eliminate them with a where clause?

Comment: Well that would just be too easy to think of that before trying 10 different case statements ;) Thank you, that should work.

Comment: @mameesh you need to either work with one item and return a single item (select TOP 1) or work with all items and get the results in to a set. What do you actually need?

Comment: I need a comma seperated list of all the values. Martin Smith's comment seems to take care of my issue

Comment: @Martin Smith, if you want to make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of the following should work

```
SELECT @DocID = COALESCE(@DocID + ',', '') + test
FROM   @Test
WHERE  test IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
SELECT @DocID = CASE
                  WHEN test IS NULL THEN @DocID /*No-op. */
                  ELSE COALESCE(@DocID + ',', '') + test
                END
FROM   @Test
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be:

```
SELECT
    @DocID = CASE
        WHEN test IS NOT NULL
            THEN COALESCE(@DocID + ',' ,'')  + test
        ELSE NULL
    END
FROM @Test
```

This will assign the last row's value of `test` to `@DocID`. This means that with this table:

```
test
--------------------
NULL
adfasdfasd
```

`@DocId` will be `adfasdfasd`

And with this table:

```
test
--------------------
adfasdfasd
NULL
```

`@DocId` will be `NULL`

Comment: I am still getting a null when does this, even without the ELSE statement

Comment: @mameesh That's because it's assigning the value (`NULL`) to the last row of `@test`. See my update.

Comment: Problem seem 4 me that @DocID is not initialized and appearance of NULL should not matter

Answer (score 1):

You only need that pattern if you have other fields involved

```
SELECT @DocID = COALESCE(@DocID + ',' + test, test, @DocID),
       @otherfield ....
FROM @Test;
```

Otherwise, as Martin commented, removing the NULLs using WHERE makes it easy

```
SELECT @DocID = COALESCE(@DocID + ',', '') + test
FROM @Test
WHERE test IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    test varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT 'adfasdfasd'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nasenbär'



DECLARE @DocID varchar(max)
Select @DocID=''
SELECT
     @DocID=@DocID + CASE
        WHEN test IS NOT NULL
            THEN Case when LEN(@DocID)>0 then ', ' else '' end + test
        ELSE ''
    END
FROM @Test

SELECT @DocID
```